# Flink job flow stops after aggregation operation with flink union streams

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am having some trouble going through the union operation. It seems like data flow stops after reduction operation. 
Here is the complete flow

Retry message ( Kafka retry topic ) +  Normal Message -> window keyBy -> reduction -> process (used for side outputs to collect messages failing a validation criteria and then putting it to the retry topic)

I did some debugging of the data pipeline and I am pretty much sure that introduction of the union operation is causing the issue. If I remove the union operator, everything works fine.

The problem is I don't see any error messages in the logs. It seems that the aggregated message is simply lost as I could see the reduction function debug point being suspended.

Comment: Without seeing the actual code (or a redacted version) it will be hard to provide any useful input. For example, where did you add the `union()` operation to the workflow?

Comment: It was due to the watermark. I wasn't pushing watermarks to the stream due to which the windowing operation was never performed. As reduction is applied consistently over the stream, I had a misunderstanding that I had no issues with windowing.